# Salesforce Connected App OAuth Process in Hybrid Mobile Application

Tags: ios, cordova, oauth, salesforce

I have created a hybrid mobile application using Salesforce Ionic starter app from this url: http://coenraets.org/blog/cordova-phonegap-3-tutorial/.

I am facing a problem, that every time a user logs in he has to allow the connected app. I think it should be only once that the user should Allow and for his subsequent logins he should be given the access normally as done with Facebook or Twitter OAuth.

I think I am not setting some parameter or making some call properly.

I am using the ForceJS SDK and calling the force.init to initialise it. It automatically calls the custom salesforce oauth plugin for cordova. Please help.

Comment: can you add relevant code fragments for how you make the oauth api aclls, and how do you store the token?

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand.  Is the problem that the user has to login more than once, or specifically that, when he/she does login, the user is presented with the Allow/Deny screen every time?

Comment: The problem is that the user is presented with the Allow/Deny screen every time which should not be the case, it should be asked only once on a device/ip/network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking (I'm not familiar with SalesForce mobile dev) if you are using the SDK provided correctly (seemed hard to misuse, only it didn't support the latest Cordova versions?) it should keep the app allowed. That indicates that the problem is with your SalesForce settings.

Inside SalesForce, go to

```
Setup | Administration Setup | Manage Apps | Connected Apps
```

and have a look at

```
Require Users to Log In
```

option. Is it set so that users only need to log in the first time they use the app, and the permissions are maintained?

If that doesn't help, try out the settings described here [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/Content/connected_app_manage_edit.htm), especially the refresh token part.